# Is possible to "download all (.zip)" artifacts as guest inTeamCity?

Tags: teamcity

I have enabled Guest Authentication in my TeamCity 9.1.6.
My artifact contains 5 MSI.

I can download individual artifacts as guest with this url:

- http://teamcity/guestAuth/repository/download/build01/lastSuccessful/ms1.msi
- http://teamcity/guestAuth/repository/download/build01/lastSuccessful/ms2.msi
- Etc.

But I cannot find the way of making the equivalent of "download all (.zip)"

[image: download all screenshot]

...using **guestAuth** (I can with authentication...)

So my questions are:

- **How can I "downloadall" artifacts as guest inTeamCity?**
- **Is possible to do it from REST API?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To download the archived artifacts for the specified build use the following request:

```
http://teamcity/guestAuth/app/rest/builds/id:XXX/artifacts/archived
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have TeamCity creating artifacts for me, so I can't verify this, but looking at the API (https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildArtifacts)
You can try something like this:
http://teamCity/guestAuth/app/rest/builds/id:100/artifacts. That should get all all the artifacts for that build.